# How to consume a Salesforce outbound message in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce

When I change a field value in Salesforce I need to be able to send an outbound message to my PHP / MySQL site, so I can parse the xml and do some changes in my database.

How to I listen to that outbound message in PHP? What do I have to setup?

Comment: To the person who down-voted: please explain why. IMHO this is a legitimate question.

Comment: It severely depends on how Salesforce sends that message, in which format, over which protocols and so on. I reckon salesforce pro's will know, but pure php guys won't :) Some extra info would be welcome. If it's XML and you can do an HTTP POST, then create a small PHP script that will consume XML and do database changes. Other than that, question is a bit too vague to give any useful answer.

Comment: I think my question is very specific. I already know how to set up the outbound message in Salesforce. I've been working with Salesforce for three years and have done this before from Salesforce to Salesforce. I don't know how to do it from Salesforce to PHP, specifically how to expose a public endpoint that listens to the outbound message that comes from Salesforce. I don't think that people who know the answer would think that this is a vague question.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an outbound message in Salesforce it will provide a link to generate a wsdl. That wsdl will represent the contract that your PHP service will need to provide. There are many wsdl2Php tools out there you can use to generate the client code.

From there you would just need to expose a public endpoint to your site and update the outbound message endpoint to point to your service.

Comment: Thanks John. As a wsdl2php I am using Force.com toolkit for php which provides a mechanism to parse the wsdl. I already set it up to work from PHP to Salesforce, so the integration from PHP to Salesforce is working right. Now I have a requirement to integrate from Salesforce to PHP. I have done this before from Salesforce to Salesforce using outbound messages. I plan to use an outbound message to call a service in php too, but I don't know how PHP receives that message, how to expose a public endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a PHP SOAP lister which I have a [Capture Salesforce Outbound Message with a PHP SOAP Listener](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/capture-salesforce-outbound-message-with-a-php-soap-listener/) explaing very detail.

Then, you [SimpleXMLElement::children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) to parse the message with namespace which is explained in my [Parse XML with namespace by SimpleXML in PHP](http://amigotechnotes.wordpress.com/2013/11/16/parse-xml-with-namespace-by-simplexml-in-php/).

Wish it helps!